# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\{\tan(x)\}dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\{\tan(x)\}dx}$$ where $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of $x$.
I mentioned the zero points of $\{\tan(x)\}$. $\{\tan(x)\}$ equals to 0 iff $x=\arctan(k)$, $k$ is an integer.
I tried to separate it into$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\int_{\arctan(k)}^{\arctan(k+1)}{(\tan(x)}-k)dx}$$
Then I found it hard to continue.
I don't think I am on the right way.

Comment: The answer is $$ 1 + \frac{i}{2}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(1-i)}{\Gamma(1+i)}\right) \approx 0.69835967953246680211. $$ It is not hard to derive it starting from the identity $$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \{ \tan x \} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^2 + 1} \, dx = 1 - \gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{k} - \arctan\frac{1}{k}\right). $$

Comment: @Oleg567, Discontinuity of the function $\{ \cdot \}$ often deteriorates the accuracy of a numerical integration. You may try some numerical computation of the sum $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\{x\}}{x^2+1} \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{x-k}{x^2+1} \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( k(\arctan k - \arctan(k+1)) + \frac{1}{2} \log\left( \frac{1+(k+1)^2}{1+k^2} \right) \right). $$ The last one will spit out a much accurate value.

Answer (score 5):

Through straightforward substitutions the computation of the original integral boils down to the computation of 
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\arctan\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(2m+1)n^{2m+1}}=\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{2m+1}\zeta(2m+1) $$
which due to $\zeta(2m+1)=\frac{1}{(2m)!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2m}}{e^x-1}\,dx$ can be written as
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x-\sin x}{x(e^x-1)}\,dx.$$
This integral is simple to approximate numerically and it is related to $\log\Gamma(1\pm i)$ [via](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$ \log\Gamma(1+z)=-\gamma z+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-zt}-1+zt}{t(e^t-1)}\,dt.$$
We have
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left\{\tan x\right\}\,dx = 1+\text{Arg}\,\Gamma(1+i).$$